# Изменить данные в строке, скопировать ее и вставить с новыми данными

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица с сообщениями:

```
messages {
    id bigint auto primary
    user_id bigint
    content text
    replaced_by bigint
    created_at int
}
```

Мне нужно в одном запросе скопировать `row` в новую стоку с новым `id` и в ней же изменить `replaced_by` на `id` этой новой строки.
Тоесть по логике мне нужно реализовать изменение сообщения без удаления старого, и когда оригинальное сообщение изменяется, то в нем изменяется только `replaced_by` и создается новое сообщение со всем содержимым старого но с новым `content`
Сейчас это сделано в двух запросах, но это не совсем то что я хочу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table messages (
    id serial primary key,
    user_id bigint,
    content text,
    replaced_by bigint,
    created_at int
);
```

---

```
insert into messages (user_id, content, created_at)
  values (22, 'aaa', extract(epoch from now()));

select * from messages ;
 id | user_id | content | replaced_by | created_at 
----+---------+---------+-------------+------------
  1 |      22 | aaa     |             | 1601909639
(1 row)
```

---

```
with nv as (
  insert into messages (user_id, content, created_at)
    select user_id, 'NEW_CONTENT', extract(epoch from now())
      from messages where id = 1 returning *
)
update messages m
  set replaced_by = nv.id
  from nv
  where m.id = 1
  RETURNING nv.*;

 id | user_id |   content   | replaced_by | created_at 
----+---------+-------------+-------------+------------
  2 |      22 | NEW_CONTENT |             | 1601909647
(1 row)
```

---

```
select * from messages ;
 id | user_id |   content   | replaced_by | created_at 
----+---------+-------------+-------------+------------
  2 |      22 | NEW_CONTENT |             | 1601909647
  1 |      22 | aaa         |           2 | 1601909639
(2 rows)
```

Обратите внимание, что в запросе, обновляющем таблицу, сейчас в двух местах стоит `id = 1` - это из тестового прогона, могу убрать из ответа.

И имейте ввиду, что этот подход будет верным только если в таблице существует запись с `id = 1`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но помимо этого мне еще нужно отредактировать `replaced_by` в источнике. именно так у меня сделано сейчас, но в двух запросах, а мне нужен один. и да запись с `id` конечно же существует

Comment: @Сергей отредактировал ответ

Comment: спасибо, это работает. Я добавил свой ответ с пояснением своей проблемы.

Comment: @Сергей понятно ) плюсую

Answer (score 1):

@nörbörnën дал верный для меня ответ.
Но я хочу добавить, что я использовал **intellij idea** и она не подсвечивает синтаксис со звездочкой `*`. Очень жаль, это сбивает с толку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это красиво только если писать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]